# What is the function of Vref/2 pin in IC ADC0804?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, adc

I've been reading the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc0804-n.pdf) of ADC0804 and still don't understand the function of the pin Vref/2. I also have applied the 2.5 volts to that pin (on simulation) but the output stay the same. Like nothing happen.

[image: ADC 0804]

Can anyone explain to me what is the function of Vref/2 Pin on ADC0804/ADC0803 ?

Comment: Have you read section 9.2.1.2.3.1 ? It explains the function of the \$V_{ref}/2\$ pin. *I also have applied the 2.5 volts to that pin* Look at figure 32, note how the \$V_{ref}/2\$ pin is also \$V_{CC}/2\$. So if your \$V_{CC}\$ = 5 V and you don't connect anything to the \$V_{ref}/2\$ pin, what would the voltage at the \$V_{ref}/2\$ pin be? 2.5 V! So indeed if you apply 2.5 V then nothing changes, it was already 2.5 V.

Comment: Try applying 2.0 V and see what happens! Then explain why the behavior is different between applying 2.5 V and 2.0 V.

Comment: I found out the step size is much smaller now, it happens because the Vref/2 pin is having different input voltage than before. Is there anything else happen?

Comment: Open the data sheet as a PDF document, type CTRL-F, enter "Vref/2" in the search box and go through all 39 occurences of what is mentioned about Vref/2.

Comment: Right then, thank you so much for the generous explanation.

Comment: The ADC full scale span is for inputs from V- to Vref, with Vref/2 being the midpoint. This flexible chip allows you drive the Vref/2 pin with half the voltage of your desired analog span (there is an internal multiply by 2 to establish Vref). If your input span is already 5V then you can leave Vref/2 disconnected, as internal resistors will default it to 2.5V so Vref=5V. The “span adjust” section of the datasheet has a nice example of how to design for a 3V input span that has a 0.5V offset. Normally this kind of gain and offset compensation would have to be done in a stage before the ADC.